# Connect to existing DynamoDB Tables from iOS App

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a web app that makes use of DynamoDB as a backend. I can set up the connection like this:

```
AWS.config.update({
    region: region,
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});
```

Using JavaScript I can easily retrieve data from a table like so:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
    TableName: tableName
};
docClient.scan(params, onScan);
function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing in an iOS App. How do I access or set up a connection to existing DynamoDB tables through Mobile Hub? All I see is an option to create new NoSQL tables, but no option to connect to an existing one.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html?

Comment: Mobile Hub is used to create a new backend, you cannot import existing resources into it.  As notionquest mentioned, if you look at the referenced docs they will explain how to interface with DynamoDB for iOS.